# How to convert/update 16bit application to 64bit

Tags: windows-10, 64-bit, application-launch, 16-bit

I am trying to run a 16bit application on windows 10 64bit but it is giving this error.
[image]
I want to know that, How can we convert or update this application in 64bit.
PS: I have source file of this application.

Comment: put the code in your ide, compile it and see what errors you get. fix them, and when it compiles, you should have a 32/64 application

Comment: Why not just use DosBox?

Answer (score 1):

Converting a 16-bit application from 16-bit to 64-bit requires it to be
recompiled using a modern compiler.
But even if this is your application and you have the source,
the differences in the API may require additional development work.

Without re-compilation,
you will need to create a virtual machine with an older version of
Windows 32-bit in order to run this application.

It was also suggested to try using
[DOSBox](https://www.dosbox.com/).

Comment: @DanielB: I forgot this fact, so deleted it out of my answer.

Comment: i dont want to use any emulator. Can you tell me which compiler would be the best

Comment: The free [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) by Microsoft should be the best.

Comment: VS code is an IDE, not a compiler. @lffat There's no "best" compiler. Each compiler has its pros and cons so it depends on your criteria to choose the one that suits you

Comment: @phuclv: An IDE will be easier to use and more supportive.

Comment: @Iffat What compiler works depends _entirely_ on what programing language the software is written in in the first place. I’m sorry to say this, but I you have to ask this question, this will be rather tough to accomplish.

Comment: @harrymc yes I know that IDEs are useful, but the OP is asking for a compiler. If you install VS Code you still need to install a compiler, and configure it to work with VS Code may be painful. Visual Studio is much easier to use and more powerful at debugging Windows applications

Comment: @phuclv: VS Code comes with a compiler.

Comment: @harrymc no it doesn't have any compiler. It doesn't even contain a C or C++ compiler and you must install an extension for each language you want to use. Look at the help of VS Code: [***VS Code is first and foremost an editor**, and relies on command-line tools to do much of the development workflow. The **C/C++ extension does not include a C++ compiler or debugger**. You will need to install these tools or use those already installed on your computer.*](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp#_install-a-compiler)

Comment: @phuclv: Of course it needs some configuring. So I change my statement to: VS Code comes with many compilers. Well, the way it really works internally, it comes with only one built-in compiler and many syntactical front-ends that can be configured in.